# Java Simple Lexer Program

Tags: java, lexical-analysis

I created a simple lexer program in Java which prompts the user for a string and displays the lexemes in that String. However, when I enter a value, if left and/or right parentheses is included in the prompt, after the left or right parentheses a null character is added which it identifies as an identifier by the program.

Also, if I don't include left and right parentheses in the user prompted String, the last character in the String is not evaluated as a lexeme.

Here is my code :

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Append
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter string : ");
    char [] arr = str.toCharArray();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,arr.length);

    determineLexemes(arr);

   }

  public static void determineLexemes(char [] arr)
  {
    int j = 0;

    String [] arrayString = new String [1000];

    String strTwo = "";

    System.out.println("Symbol Table");

    System.out.println("Lexeme\t\tToken");

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {

       if(arr[i] == '+')
            {
                System.out.println("+ \t\t ADD_OP");
            }

       if(arr[i] == '-')
            {
                System.out.println("- \t\t SUB_OP");
            }

       if(arr[i] == '*')
            {
                System.out.println("* \t\t MULT_OP");
            }

       if(arr[i] == '/')
            {
                System.out.println("/ \t\t DIV_OP");
            }

       if(arr[i] == '(')
            {
                System.out.println("( \t\t LEFT_PAREN");
            }

       if(arr[i] == ')')
            {
                System.out.println(") \t\t RIGHT_PAREN");
            }

       if(arr[i] == '=')
            {
                System.out.println("= \t\t EQUAL_OP");
            }

       if(Character.isLetter(arr[i]) || Character.isDigit(arr[i]))
        {
            strTwo += arr[i];
        }

       if(!Character.isLetter(arr[i]) && !Character.isDigit(arr[i]))
        {
            if(!(Character.isWhitespace(arr[i])))
            {
                arrayString[j] = strTwo;
                System.out.println(arrayString[j] + "\t\t" + "IDENTIFIER");
                strTwo = "";
                j++;

            }
        }
    }


 }
}
```

Any help to resolve the problem is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some sample input?

Comment: This could, and should, be debugged as a command line app. so I'm removing the Swing tag.

Comment: One input is (a + b) which displays all the lexemes but adds a new lexeme between ( and a. Another input is a + b. Which only displays + and a as lexemes (i.e. it skips taking b as a lexeme).

Comment: Try using something like `if (!(Character.isWhitespace(arr[i])) && !strTwo.isEmpty()) {`

Comment: Also, let me introduce you to me little friend `System.out.printf`, `System.out.printf("%s%20s%n", "=", "EQUAL_OP");`

Comment: Also, change `if (!Character.isLetter(arr[i]) && !Character.isDigit(arr[i])) {` to `if (!Character.isLetter(arr[i]) || !Character.isDigit(arr[i])) {` as a character can't be a letter and a digit at the same time

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Thanks. Adding !strTwo.isEmpty() solved one of the problems as now when I enter left and right parentheses, it does not display an additional null lexeme, which earlier this program identified as an identifier. However, the other problem still exists (i.e., if I don't include left and right parentheses, the last character is not taken as a lexeme). E.g.: if a + b is entered, b is not still taken as a lexeme.

Comment: @user3023315 See my last comment ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Thanks a lot. Now the problem is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not maintain state in your lexer. Recognizing a regular language can be done with a finite automaton, which is a simple mechanism that keeps track of its state (and may maintain a buffer for accumulating longer lexemes).

So, initially you should set the state to S0, and each operator and parentheses is recognized, and you stay in state S0. For a letter, you enter SI, and remain, while recognizing in SI for more letters and digits. An operator terminates SI, and emits the operator and returns to S0. - Recognizing a digit in S0, enters SN, and you handle this in a way similar to SI.

```
enum State { S0, IDENTIFIER, NUMBER } 

State state = State.S0;
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
switch( state ){
case S0:
    switch(arr[i]){
    case '+':
        System.out.println("+ \t\t ADD_OP");
        break;
    //...
    default:
        if(Character.isLetter(arr[i])){
            strTwo = ""; strTwo += arr[i];
            state = State.IDENTIFIER;
        }
        if(Character.isDigit(arr[i])){
            strTwo = ""; strTwo += arr[i];
            state = State.NUMBER;
        }
        break;
    }
case IDENTIFIER:
    if(Character.isLetter(arr[i]) || Character.isDigit(arr[i])){
        strTwo += arr[i];
    } else {
        System.out.println(strTwo + "\t\t" + "IDENTIFIER");
        i--;
        state = State.S0;
    }
        break;
case NUMBER:
    if(Character.isDigit(arr[i])){
        strTwo += arr[i];
    } else {
         System.out.println(strTwo + "\t\t" + "NUMBER");
         i--;
         State = State.S0;      
    }
    break;
}
```

Something is missing here: Handling a number or identifier at the end of the input string. This can be determined by examining variable state and using the contents of strTwo.

Comment: Can you explain me a bit more on maintaining state. The description you have provided is complicated to me,

Comment: Think of a "finite automata' as basically a directional graph, each 'node' in the graph is a 'state' and you can only be in a single 'node' at a time (technically this is 'Deterministic Finite Automata', but hey...) Its what is used for this, Then you have 'transitions' from one state to another, these transitions are the valid input characters... and you move around the graph while you 'read' characters and if you read a character you don't have a transition, that means the input 'sentence' doesn't match your grammar(language the lexer recognizes)

Comment: @user3023315 My code snipped  is tolerable now (except for the `i--`, which I hate doing in a for statement) although there are other (better) implementation techniques. Google DFA (what mawalker wrote), or lexer, or regular language parsing.